# Android bytecode instrumentation

Tags: android, bytecode, android-instrumentation

I want to extract the CPU and memory usage information of android application using byte code instrumentation ? Can anyone tell how to perform byte code instrumentation in android ?

I have come across ASMDEX and Dex-maker which will perform byte code instrumentation but sufficient documentation is not available.

I want to know exactly where to put the instrumentation file (Assuming that we have only .apk file with us)

Comment: The libraries come with documentation. Read about the Android byte code format and create the apropriate code. However, injecting code in Android is difficult as the classes share a common constant pool. It is easier to generate sublasses and load them via a `PathClassLoader`.